# Django Smart Select data checking

Tags: python, django

Im currently developing a web apps system using Python Django, and using Django Smart_Select for my profile edit page
Under Profile Edit Page, there are Country, State and Parliament for each user profile

Some state dont have parliment (just for example)
so, during new user registration, i would do checking, if user chose the state that contain Parliament, then the Parliament field is required, else the field can be empty.

in forms.py my ModelForm of state is using ModelChoiceField

I am stucking on this for few hours, please help... Thank you very much, your cooperation will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/):

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):

parliament = …
state = ModelChoiceField(…)

def clean_parliament(self):
    if self.cleaned_data[“state”].has_parliament() and not self.cleaned_data[“parliament”]:
        raise forms.ValidationError(“parliament is required for this state!”)

    return self.cleaned_data[“parliament”]
```

---

This assumes that your `State` model has a `has_parliament` method which returns True or False based on wether or not the state has a parliament. You can adapt the code above to do any other kind of error checking.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, would you mind please provide some example for the method "has_parliament" ?

Comment: It depends entirely on how your State and Parliament model are implemented. I just provided an example of good code practice (using model methods to make views/forms simpler) but how you check wether or not a State has a Parliament is up to you and out of the scope of your question. A simple use of related model managers should be sufficient (`return self.parliaments_set.all().count() != 0`). This, off course, assumes that Parliament has a `model.ForeignKey(State)` declared.

Comment: Thank you very much ! appreciated !